# How to Store Local Arrays Properly from subsequent requests in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to have a local array that stores "last messages" (inbox view). In my service i do a GET request that returns a data structure like this:

```
[{id:1, from_user:1, to_user:2, message:"bar", has_been_read:false}, 
{id:2, from_user:3, to_user:2, message:"foo", has_been_read:false}]
```

The server only sends last messages with has_been_read == false, this is the code for the service:

```
$scope.unreadMessages = []

$scope.GetUnreadMessages = function(){

      $localStorage.AllMessages.push($scope.unreadMessages)

       UserService.GetUnreadMessages()
            .success(function (data) {

              data = angular.fromJson(data);
              $scope.unreadMessages.push(data);

              }).
            error(function(error) {         
        //do something
          });
}

$scope.GetUnreadMessages()
```

Let's say In my given example json above I read id:1 which cause the, has_been_read to become true.. on the next request it will only return the data id:2, which is correct.. but my problem is the new request data replaces ALL my old data. so what i want to happen is, even if i read id:1 unless i deleted it or i have a new message from the same user, I still want to keep it when i make new requests.. I know my code is wrong just don't know how to go about this..

Comment: You need to save to local storage read messages.

Comment: @dfsq can you please give example code im really new to programming

Comment: Post the code how you mark message read.

Comment: @dfsq when i make a Get Request for the conversation of a specific user, the backend sends all of them as true.. so upon clicking the item in my inbox  it changes to true..

Comment: Ideally the server should send you both read/unread messages, for it is the entity that will keep your clients in sync. With your current implementation each client will exclusively have its own copy of read messages.

Comment: i don't have control over the backend :( @KabirRoy, im pretty sure this is doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to save the responses grouped by `from_user`:

```
.success(function(unreadMessages){
    angular.forEach(unreadMessages, function(unreadMessage){
        // if conversation from a user exists
        if(localStorage.getItem(unreadMessage.from_user)){
            var conversation = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(unreadMessage.from_user));
            conversation.push(unreadMessage);
            localStorage.setItem(unreadMessage.from_user, JSON.stringify(conversation));
        } else {
            var conversation = [];
            conversation.push(unreadMessage);
            localStorage.setItem(unreadMessage.from_user, JSON.stringify(conversation));
        }
    });
})
```